# How to deploy TDE templates via ml-gradle

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to deploy TDE templates by running method `tde.templateInsert()`?

I need to validate templates before deployment.

How to disable templates before redeploying new ones or updating existing ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy TDE templates with [`tde.templateInsert()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/tde.templateInsert).

It is provided as a convenience method that will first validate (which you can also perform by using [`tde:validate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/tde.validate)), then inserts the template into the schema database, and then reindex matching documents.

If you are deploying templates with the same URI, then you can re-insert the template.

If you have a set of templates that are no longer needed and want to drop, you should [set them as disabled](https://developer.marklogic.com/recipe/disable-tde-templates/) and allow for the matching docs to be reindexed.

You can see how many documents still need to be reindexed by executing the following:

```
xdmp:forest-counts(
  xdmp:forest("Documents"),
  ("reindex-tde-templates", "reindex-deleted-tde-templates")
)
```

When reindexing has completed, those TDE templates can safely be deleted. You can delete a Template using `xdmp:document-delete()`.

If you delete the Template without disabling, you may be left with some wasted space from obsolete indexes.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_94831

> Accidental deletion of a template can be fixed by:
>
> - Reinserting the template in a disabled state.
> - Reusing the same template document URI for a new template.
> - Manually reindexing the database.

If you are using ml-gradle for your deployments, then you just need to put your TDE templates under the `tde` directory of the schema database directory. i.e. `/src/main/mySchemaDB/tde/foo.tde`. Take a look at the ml-gradle [examples/schemas-project](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples/schemas-project) for a practical example.

Comment: Where I should place tde.templateInsert() script in build.gradle?

Comment: ml-gradle will deploy your TDE to the schemas DB if you place them in the appropriate directory. I've updated the answer with a pointer to the example schemas-project, which deploys a TDE.

Comment: Am I understand correctly: I no need to disable templates if I replace them in the appropriate directory?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding. If you are updating a TDE you should be able to just re-deploy. However, if you are looking to delete it, then you should first disable and allow to reindex, then delete.